# How can I concatenate and transpose two ranges of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Form linked to a Google Sheet. It has a number of questions with responses that I need grouped into specific columns. I also need to keep the columns in the order they're in.

I was working with a formula someone helped me with to do one single range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Job Responsibilities";IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(H2:V),,100))))})
```

However in the instance I am having problems, I need to group together the answers that are in columns W - AK and also BA - BO into one cell.

I tried something like

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Supporting SAP Stream";IF(B2:B="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(W2:AK)TRANSPOSE(BA2:BO),,100))))})
```

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Supporting SAP Stream";IF(B2:B="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(W2:AK, BA2:BO),,100))))})
```

But that makes an error.

Is there another modification I can make to concatenate and transpose the values in these cells?

---

Here is [a link to a Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16KbQbgtxddOSXf6QPY9h9OZ77kTSf45AHPQLgpCOkPs/edit#gid=2100307022) showing most of what I'm referring to. It's from an earlier iteration, so it's not 100% exact with what I said above, but the goal is still the same. In this Sheet, I would like to concatenate what's in Columns U - AG and AU - BF.

Comment: Please share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet, with permissions set (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." As it stands, the volunteer contributors here would need to manually enter data into their own sheet before they could even begin, which is a large deterrent. Help us help you.

Comment: Updated the original post with a link to a Sheet that I was working on previously. If you want to stick the formula at the end, like in Column BI or something, I'll look for it there and can watch while you work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, based on the data in your sheet:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Supporting SAP Stream";IF(B2:B="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(U2:AG);TRANSPOSE(AU2:BG)},,100))))})`

Try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Supporting SAP Stream";IF(!B2:B="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(W2:AK); TRANSPOSE(BA2:BO)},,100))))})`

Comment: This resulted in an error on my Sheet. Updated the OP with a link to an example if you want to work through it with me.

Comment: Could you point me to the cell that has the expected output from your previous formula?

Comment: Thanks so much! The second formula did the trick.